# How to give o/p of one command to the argument of another command in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

i have compiled Linux kernel now i want to copy all *.ko files in one separate folder

so

```
find ./kernel -name "*.ko"
```

It will give me the list of all .ko files. 
Now i want to give this list as argument to cp command.

like

```
cp -rpf $filer_ko temp/
```

so how to do this in shell script and on terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all the files that end in `.ko` and will pipe that list in a loop that iterates over each file (even if they have spaces -- that's probably not the case here though) and will copy each file in the temp directory.

```
find ./kernel -name "*.ko" | while read file; do cp $file temp/ ; done
```

Comment: But... but... but... the `-exec` flag of `find` does exactly that!

Answer (score 0):

As per what i think the below code should satisfy your need. I only gave a dry run to it.
Store the result in a `variable` and then `looping` to extract data one by one

```
#! /bin/bash
$op = find ./kernel -name *.ko"

for zf in $op
do
    cp -rpf $zf
    tail $zf
done
```

Comment: That will not handle file names with spaces in them.

Comment: why ? what's the problem with this?

Comment: If there is a file name called `bla blue` this for loop will iterate over it by first assigning `bla` to `zf` and then assigning `blue` to `zf` thus resulting in a failure.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the explanation. I'll try this out when i get to the system.

Comment: Many things wrong with this code: assignment looks like `var=value` with no spaces and no leading `$`; you need `$(find ...)` to actually execute it; always quote `"$variables"` unless you know specifically when to leave the quotes off.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` is normally used for this. But not here.

See, `find` has this ability builtin

Try this:

```
find ./kernel -name "*.ko" -exec cp -rpf {} temp/ \;
```

Comment: Assuming GNU tools, `find ./kernel -name "*.ko" -exec cp -rpf -t temp/ {} +`

Answer (score 0):

another approach: use xargs

```
find ./kernel -name "*.ko"  -print0 | xargs -0 cp -rpf -t temp/
```